# If I build a component in the latest version of Angular, can that component be used by apps built with earlier Angular versions?

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to build a component using the latest version of Angular.

However, the goal is for that component to used in two different Angular applications - one built with Angular 6, and another build using Angular 10.

Is that possible?

In other words - can my component, once built, be used in apps built with earlier Angular versions?

Or, do I need to build the component using the same version of Angular as the application(s) that will include it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the answer is no:

From here:

https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#ensuring-library-version-compatibility

> The Angular version used to build an application should always be the
> same or greater than the Angular versions used to build any of its
> dependent libraries. For example, if you had a library using Angular
> version 12, the application that depends on that library should use
> Angular version 12 or later. Angular does not support using an earlier
> version for the application